# What is the VC Accelerator Editor in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Is this for C++?

Is this for C#?

What are Accelerator Editors in general?

EDIT

It seems that Accelerators are Keyboard Shortcuts. So now I really just want to now if VC is C# or C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your reference?  I find a [Microsoft tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ac6d7wde.aspx) to edit keyboard accelerators, meant to be used from VC++.

> An accelerator table is a Windows
>   resource that contains a list of
>   accelerator keys (also known as
>   shortcut keys) and the command
>   identifiers that are associated with
>   them. A program can have more than one
>   accelerator table.
>
> Normally, accelerators are used as
>   keyboard shortcuts for program
>   commands that are also available on a
>   menu or toolbar. However, you can use
>   the accelerator table to define key
>   combinations for commands that don't
>   have a user-interface object
>   associated with them.

Comment: I was referring actually to keyboard shortcuts, so I guess all that is left is whether vc is c++ or c#.

Comment: "VC" is commonly used to refer to Visual C++.